# Null parameter on API POST

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

Web Controller:

```
public void SignIn(UserInfo user, IList<string> roleList, bool rememberMe = false)
{
    Audit audit = new Audit()
        {                
            UserName = user.UserName,
            Role = roleList[0].ToString(),
            ControllerAccessed = "Login",
            MethodAccessed = "Login",
            TimeAccessed = DateTime.UtcNow,
            IsLogin = true,               
            Is_Report = false,
            Report_Type = null,
            Report_Name = null
        };
     PostAPIData<int>(apiBaseUrl + "api/AuditAPI/LogUIAudit", audit);
}

public class Audit
{        
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }        
    public string ControllerAccessed { get; set; }
    public string MethodAccessed { get; set; }
    public DateTime TimeAccessed { get; set; }
    public bool IsLogin { get; set; }
    public bool Is_Report { get; set; }
    public string Report_Type { get; set; }
    public string Report_Name { get; set; }
    
}

public T PostAPIData<T>(string url, object obj)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, obj);
        responseTask.Wait();
        var result = responseTask.Result;
    }
}
```

In above `SignIn` method, I'm passing 2 different api calls with respective model classes. So I defined it as `obj` in the `PostAPIData` method. and one of the `url` is `https://localhost:44306/api/AuditAPI/LogUIAudit`. When this code hits the below API Controller, parameters turns empty:

API Controller:

```
[Route("api/AuditAPI/LogUIAudit")]
[HttpPost]
public int LogUIAudit(Audit AuditEntry)
{
}
```

I tried below conversions. But none of them works.

1:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var responseTask = client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, content);
```

2:

```
StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AuditEntry), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var responseTask = client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

3:

```
Audit AuditEntry = (Audit)obj;
StringContent content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(AuditEntry), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var responseTask = client.PostAsync(url, content);
```

Both client and server is running. But when I debug the code, all the properties of that model class are shown as null.

Comment: Why is it that your API controller has no attribute specifying where to get the parameter from? What do you expect where it is taken from? Where do you expect it is sent?

Comment: You sent the request from client to server and are waiting for the server to send a response back.  The server did not send back a response so you are waiting.  The problem could be the server is not running, you are sending to the wrong URL, or the server got an error and did not respond.

Comment: Are you `await`ing `responseTask`?

Comment: Can you share the structure of `object obj`?

Comment: Use `[FromBody]` attribute to bind your model correctly: `public int LogUIAudit([FromBody]Audit AuditEntry)`

Comment: Thanks! [FromBody] worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your data in your API `Controller`, you should use the [FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) attribute to bind your model correctly:

```
[Route("api/AuditAPI/LogUIAudit")]
[HttpPost]
public int LogUIAudit([FromBody]Audit AuditEntry)
{

}
```